# Wrong UTM zone settings in GPS receiver

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, gps, utm, rtkgps+

I recently made a survey with an rtk GPS in an area within the UTM zone 32 N. Alas, the instrument was set to work on zone 33 N. When I load the points on a map applying the zone 32 projection (EPSG 32632) they are displayed far more west than they should be. Using the 32 N projection instead (EPSG 32633) puts them way east. The coordinates are in easting and northing format (see first three rows of the dataset here below).

Is there a way of converting the GPS readings "from 33 to 32" UTM zones?

```
P_Id Easting    Northing    Hellips.Elev
0   503815.028  5069932.565 214.429
1   497760.019  5080841.423 207.929
2   497747.633  5080748.276 205.616
```

Comment: What program(s) are you working with?

Comment: If possible, the best would be to output the coordinates in WGS84 and then convert them to UTM. This way, hopefully the conversion will be correctly executed.

Comment: I think you're in trouble. The coordinates you have look perfectly reasonable for 32N--very close to the middle of the zone. If they had been collected in 33N, they should have much larger easting values.

Comment: NGS NCAT software using 32N gives Latitude
N45° 46′ 58.59361″
N454658.59361
45.7829426690
Longitude
E09° 02′ 56.67953″
E0090256.67953
9.0490776474

Comment: Using 33N gives Latitude
N45° 46′ 58.59361″
N454658.59361
45.7829426690
Longitude
E15° 02′ 56.67953″
E0150256.67953
15.0490776474

Comment: Is the data supposed to be in Italy or Slovenia?

Comment: @Pointdump: I'm using a mix of qgis and python programming with geopandas and pyproj

Comment: @fastest I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: @mkennedy: maybe they look reasonable because the area is very close to the edge with zone 33. The coordinates you obtained using NGS NCAT are not where I made the survey but way more west. This place is in Italy, north from Venice.

Comment: Thanks to all to contributed, in the end I solved like this:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who contributed, in the end, I solved like this:

- From the easting and northing coordinates, create two shapefiles: one
  with epsg 32632 and the other 32633 (utm zones 32 and 33
  respectively).
- Load the two in qgis (or arcgis) and export the zone 32 (westmost)
  reprojected in wgs 84 (epsg 4326).
- Make a copy of the westmost one and edit it bringing all the points
  onto the eastmost one (use snapping for better precision). Now you
  have a westlayer (wl) and an eastlayer (ey) in the same reference
  system. Add longitude and latitude fields to the two and compute
  their values (in qgis $x, $y).
- Use python to iterate through the wl and el, calculate the delta x
  and delta y of each point and create a new point having:  `x = wx + (delta_x/2)` and `y = wy + (delta_y/2)`.
- Create a shapefile with these points which are now displayed in the
  correct locations.